# Error: The underlying provider failed on Open with EntityFramework in IIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, iis

I am getting intermittent errors as per the below stack trace. I am using C# Entity Framework with SQL Server 2012 enterprise running on a separate server computer. I can connect and query the DB using SSMS from the development machine.

**For my case, it only happens when deploying to IIS 7.5. Everything runs perfectly fine in local (under Visual Studio 2015/2017). This is .Net Framework 4.7.1**

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) StackTrace : at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c) at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.b__2() at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0() at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation) at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation) at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()

**Connection String:**

```
  <connectionStrings><add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.MyReplicationModel.csdl|res://*/Model.MyReplicationModel.ssdl|res://*/Model.MyReplicationModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=********;initial catalog=**********;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=*******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/></connectionStrings>
```

Can you help me about problem?

Thank you all

Comment: The issue is with the connection string to the database. Check the connection string that you use. The issue may be the syntax of the string, the wrong database server name or the credentials used to connect.

Comment: I shared the connection string. I think connection string isn't wrong.

Comment: You have, quite rightly, redacted the parts of the connection string that would be the problem. Only you can validate them. The error message says at least one of these is wrong.

Comment: From the error message `The server was not found or was not accessible.` Either you have the wrong data source, or the username/password are wrong.

Comment: Your firewall could also block your access.
your Server might have an incorrect setup, can you connect to your remote server, in a management tool or similar?